# AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, pytorch

Решил обучить нейросеть на PyTorch, при принте `torch.cuda.is_available()` выводит `False`
вводя nvidia-smi он видит мою RTX 3060. Юзал PyTorch 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить версию с CUDA
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`